# Linux: monitor my own internet usage page by page

Tags: linux, monitoring, tcp, internet

I have a monthly broadband subscription which rolls over on the 23rd of each month. I had arrived near the end of my usage so I was carefully checking that I didn't go over my limit - they **crucify** you for excess usage!

So, when my usage didn't roll over on the 23rd, I rang them to check what was up (turned out that it was due to their end-user web interface not being entirely not up to date - they're quick enough to bill though!).

Now to the question - the agent told me that I had used 2.5MB (or similar figures) **PER PAGE** just to check my usage (the only pages I had accessed on the two days in question). To say I was **shocked** is an understatement. These are not fancy pages - v. little graphics &c.

So, now I want to check up my internet usage (per page). Can anyone point me to useful Linux tools in this domain? I have Googled but have found that everything is either Windows and/or doesn't give results by page. I don't want something that works in real time, but rather keeps a record, preferably something I can put in a database or at least a spreadsheet.

This is not a shopping list question - I just want tool names - not "but blah1 is better than blah2..." type debates (I can research this myself).

***NOTE:*** in response to Warren Young's answer.

1) Don't want all data usage (well, I do, but on a URL by URL (page by page) basis)

2) As mentioned in my original question, my ISP's net usage tracker is about as useful as tits on a bull - days behind, and anyway, has no granularity whatsoever.

3) As I said to @peterph, I am thinking about something browser based (I use Chrome) for ad-hoc analyses, but I would like a daemon to do this for me automatically.

4) As I said to @SailorCire, I'm more of a DBA guy and have enough on my plate without going down a development route - I'm not being lazy, I also think I don't really have the skills.

Finally, I was thinking of doing something with Wireshark - do you think this might be a good route? Or even Snort?

Comment: Something really primitive would be wrapping a script around tcpdump.

Comment: I'm more of a database guy and would prefer something ready-made if possible - ./configure, make, make install (or similar) would be my preference.

Comment: *"not fancy pages"* - today's pages usually include tons of JavaScript, that can cause heavy traffic without you even noticing it - consider plugins like AdBlock, NoScript for Firefox.

Comment: Another good point - thanks for that. I'm leaning towards a browser-based solution for individual pages, but I would like to have (or be able to switch on) a "daemon" type service which would record my usage, rather than me having to constantly check on a page by page basis.

Comment: 3. MRTG and Cacti *are* daemons with browser front-ends. Their back-end DBs are open for ad-hoc analysis already. As for the Wireshark idea, no, bad idea. That's why we have MRTG and Cacti in the first place.

Comment: So, @WarrenYoung, are you saying that MRTG actually contains the information that I want - it's just that the graphs that I looked didn't present that information?

Comment: I'm saying they're the closest existing tools that I know of. If you need something more specific, you should look into digging the info you need out of their databases rather than hold out for something so uncommonly specific. Unless you're hoping for someone to write custom software for you, you're probably not going to find exactly what you want. What most people want in this area is an answer to the question, "How close am I to my ISP's plan limit?" not "How big was that web page I downloaded 3 weeks ago?"

Comment: I know that I can't expect people to start beavering away writing software just because I have a non-standard request :-) (would be nice though). I did find one piece of [code](https://www.google.ie/?gws_rd=ssl#q=tcptrack) that might fit the bill - maybe with a bit of massaging? Unfortunately, my C/C++ days are way behind me.  I think the idea that you mentioned about using a browser extension might be the way to go. All the same, I find it hard to believe that nobody, ever, has had a requirement like this. I'll leave the post for another couple of days and then mark your response as correct.

Comment: And there is no need to put **Edit** in your question. Everyone can see the [edit history](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/186641/revisions). This is not an improved question, it is just statements glued onto a question about my capabilities of pointing something out. And thanks should never be in a question.

Comment: 1) "Everyone can see the edit history" - yes, but why give people the trouble of clicking on the link? 2) "it is just statements glued onto a question" It saves me making a new answer to my own question and adds clarity overall IMHO - not enough room for a comment. 3) "thanks should never be in a question" I'm acknowledging @WarrenYoung 's input. If you feel strongly about my actions, then flag them for a moderator, but I feel that I have sufficient command of the English language to make myself clear in the way I see fit.

Comment: It would have been clearer to put your responses to my answer as comments *on* my answer. Then there wouldn't need to be any attribution. It would be clear who you are responding to.

Comment: FireFox plugin. There are others: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/422328/page-size-firefox-add-on. Also with Firebug: http://getfirebug.com/network

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to skin that cat:

- If you want a graph of all data usage over a given period plus other summary statistics, the standard tools for that on Linux are [MRTG](http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/) and [Cacti](http://cacti.net/).
- Your ISP may offer a web API that lets [Net Usage Item](http://netusage.iau5.com/) periodically check your usage and report it with a "fuel gauge" in the browser. It works in Firefox and Chrome. Pulling the data this way is probably less expensive in terms of data transfer than going to an interactive web page.
- If you want to see if your ISP's support people are spouting nonsense when they tell you that those simple pages weigh 2.5 MiB each, then you already have what you need to answer the question: your browser's development tools.

  In the past 2-3 years, all the major browser providers have added [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)-like tool sets to their browsers. Firefox includes its own developer tools now, too, so that Firebug itself is increasingly unnecessary.

  The keystroke for this is usually <kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl-Shift-I</kbd>.

  What you're looking for is the Network tab. ([Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor), [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network)) When you open a page with this panel open, it gives you all kinds of details about what happens on the network when that page loads, including its page weight.
- If you're asking for something that will let you dig back into history and perform long-term analyses that let you answer questions like "What is the median page size I downloaded during the month?" then I don't know of anything currently in existence. If it doesn't in fact exist, you could build it by accessing the data collected by MRTG or Cacti.

Comment: To @WarrenYoung, thanks for replying. I've answered your points in an edit.